# Foreach loop goes out of range in an IEnumerable collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I tried to send a collection to view with `ViewBag`.

Controller:

```
var list = db.Groups.Where(g => g.Active).OrderByDescending(g => g.Priority);
ViewBag.Groups = list;
```

then loop on this collection in View:

View:

```
@{
    var Groups = ViewBag.Groups as IEnumerable<Group>;
}
...
@foreach (var item in Groups)
{...}
```

But I got exception

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I put some breakpoint. This collection has 4 items but `foreach` loop trying to loop over 5th item! So I get the null reference exception.

Can someone tell me what exactly happening?

I tried this with `List<>` but same problem.

Comment: give me team viewer

Comment: Change `ViewBag.AllGroups = list;` to `ViewBag.Groups = list;` ?

Comment: @mybirthname: you and s.akbari are wrong, this question is not about nullvalueexception.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: i found problem. i had **another** object (but same class)  in ViewBag and that object does not exist (because null assigned to it  in controller) . but VS showed me wrong place and tried to loop over 5th item of a list with 4 item!. so i think it is a bug about ViewBag.